# bat file in win 10 startup folder

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

Made a simple script using **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** file to remove all files from:

**`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp`**.

I want to delete for all users on the PC when they log in to their profile.
So I put the bat file into **[windows](/questions/tagged/windows)** start up folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Here is my bat file:

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp
if exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp" del /F /Q *.*
```

**Question is:**

Is this method safe?
If not, what could go wrong? Should I have some kind of error handle?

And can I safely add `if exist "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\CrashDump" del /F /Q .` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not one line with safe operator redirects (Conditional Execution **`&&`**) and system variables:

```
%userprofile%     // For your folder C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\CrashDump
%temp% or %tmp%   // For your folder C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

```
2>nul @(cd /d "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\CrashDump" && del /q /f *.*)
```

```
2>nul @(cd /d "%temp%" && del /q /f *.*)
```

**Obs.: 1** Replace **`cd`**  to **`cd /d`**

**Obs.: 2** **`2>nul`** can omit error in the execution of the commands within the block(`command`<sub>**1**</sub>, `command`<sub>**2**</sub>, `command`<sub>**n**</sub>...) such as a non-existent folder, file in use, etc.

**Obs.: 3** **[A command can output to multiple streams and it's allowed to redirect each of them to a different destination. So `2>nul` and `1>nul` simply said that the error output and the normal output will be redirected to nul. So nothing will be outputted.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599228/8177207)**

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[CD](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

---

Comment: Thanks alot! And did learn some new stuff! Did not run with @(cd...) for me, so i just added @echo off in top.

Comment: @paperthins the @(block) in one line code/command can be useful inside other code language when you invoke cmd commands.

Answer (score 4):

It is not safe. First you need check the existence of the folder before changing current directory to it.

```
@echo off
set "_path=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp"
if exist "%_path%" (
  cd "%_path%" 
  del /F /Q *.*
)
```

Comment: You don't need to check if you used the accepted method via &&.  cd [path] && del /f /q *.*    If the cd [path] fails, the del command will not run.